# Error al crear proyecto xamarin vs2015 pro

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Error con Xamarin 
esto es lo que hago
1-instale vs2015 pro licenciado con xamarin
2-creo proyecto cross-plataform-blank app(xamarin form portable)
3-arroja error "SE ENCONTRO UN PROBLEMA AL CREAR EL SUBPROYECTO 'APP8.ANDROID'" REFERENCIA A OBJETO NO ESTABLECIDA COMO INSTANCIA DE UN OBJETO"
4-envio imagen de error
[image: imagen con descripcion de error]

Comment: Te está diciendo que actualices Visual Studio, lo has hecho?

Answer (score 0):

yo encontré errores similares cuando empecé a utilizar Xamarin, aunque no éste en concreto.
Lo que puedo sugerirte es la instalación de varios paquetes contenidos en Visual Studio, muchos de los problemas que tuve eran debidos a que me faltaban librerías, paquetes, repositorios, etc. Quizá así se solucione tu problema.

Para ello, en Windows, debes ir a:

> Panel de control -> Desinstalar Programas -> "tu visual studio 2015" -> ***Cambiar***.
>   En el asistente que aparece pulsas en ***Modificar***.
>   Seleccionas **Desarrollo para móviles multiplataforma** -> **Kit de desarrollo software y herramientas comunes** y marcas todos los paquetes disponibles que se refieran a Android.
>   Pulsas en ***Siguiente*** y esperas a que se instalen.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda,
un saludo!